# Looking to complete this approach to solve an IMO 1986 Problem

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math, coloring

> **IMO 1986 Problem 6.** Let $S$ be a finite subset of $\mathbb Z^2$.
> Show that it is possible to color the points of $S$ red or blue in such a way that for any line parallel to one of the coordinate axes, the number of points on the line colored red and the number of points on the line colored blue differ by at most 1.

Following is an approach to the problem. I think it can be completed to a rigorous proof, but so far I am unable to do so. *Please note that I am NOT looking for alternate solutions to the problem.*

**Attempt.**

Assume that the statement is false, and suppose $S$ is a subset with the smallest number of elements which serves as a counterexample to the statement.
Suppose we can find 4 points $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$ in $S$ with the property that there exists integers $a, b$ and $r, s$ such that
$$
A = (r, a), \quad B = (s, a), \quad C = (s, b), \quad D = (r, b)
$$
(in other words,$A$, $B$, $C$ and $D$ are vertices of a rectangle whose sides are parallel to the axes).
Define $S' = S\setminus \{A, B, C, D\}$.
By minimality of the size of $S$ we can find a coloring of $S'$ satisfying the requirement of the problem, and then color $A$ red, $B$ blue, $C$ red, and $D$ blue to get a legitimate coloring of $S$.
This would be a contradiction since $S$ was a counterexample.
*Thus we conclude that one cannot find 4 points in $S$ which are vertices of a rectangle with axis-parallel sides.*

This conclusion seems to pose severe restriction on $S$ and in any example that I have taken with $S$ satisfying this restriction, I have been able to color $S$ legitimately.

It may help to note that one may translate rows and columns of $S$ and make $S$ "look nicer."

Comment: What would be a generalisation of a rectangle to a larger configuration you could exclude? And can you exclude smaller configurations than a rectangle (eg a point with no other points in its row or column)?

Comment: This sort of rectangle forms a cycle in the graph of points which can "see" each other. I think other cycles, not including ones within a single line, could have similar effects on coloring restrictions.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I think one can generalize to exclude "cylces" which can be formed by alternate horizontal and vertical moves. It's still not clear how to finish from there but I am thinking.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have been able to complete the proof.